# ifDescr but no ifInOctets

Tags: snmp, cacti

Cacti 0.8.7i | cisco WS-C2924-XL | Traffic monitoring

```
[root@centos cacti]# snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <cisco_switch_IP> IF-MIB::ifDescr
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: VLAN1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: FastEthernet0/1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: FastEthernet0/2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = STRING: FastEthernet0/3
IF-MIB::ifDescr.5 = STRING: FastEthernet0/4
IF-MIB::ifDescr.6 = STRING: FastEthernet0/5
IF-MIB::ifDescr.7 = STRING: FastEthernet0/6
IF-MIB::ifDescr.8 = STRING: FastEthernet0/7
IF-MIB::ifDescr.9 = STRING: FastEthernet0/8
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10 = STRING: FastEthernet0/9
IF-MIB::ifDescr.11 = STRING: FastEthernet0/10
IF-MIB::ifDescr.12 = STRING: FastEthernet0/11
IF-MIB::ifDescr.13 = STRING: FastEthernet0/12
IF-MIB::ifDescr.14 = STRING: FastEthernet0/13
IF-MIB::ifDescr.15 = STRING: FastEthernet0/14
IF-MIB::ifDescr.16 = STRING: FastEthernet0/15
IF-MIB::ifDescr.17 = STRING: FastEthernet0/16
IF-MIB::ifDescr.18 = STRING: FastEthernet0/17
IF-MIB::ifDescr.19 = STRING: FastEthernet0/18
IF-MIB::ifDescr.20 = STRING: FastEthernet0/19
IF-MIB::ifDescr.21 = STRING: FastEthernet0/20
IF-MIB::ifDescr.22 = STRING: FastEthernet0/21
IF-MIB::ifDescr.23 = STRING: FastEthernet0/22
IF-MIB::ifDescr.24 = STRING: FastEthernet0/23
IF-MIB::ifDescr.25 = STRING: FastEthernet0/24
IF-MIB::ifDescr.26 = STRING: Null0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.27 = STRING: VLAN2
```

*snmpwalk -v 1 -c public  IF-MIB::ifSpeed* 
Output is ....(omitted)....IF-MIB::ifSpeed.27 = Gauge32: 10000000

```
[root@centos cacti]# snmpwalk -v 1 -c public <cisco_switch_IP> IF-MIB::ifInOctets
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 219358591
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 381820030
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 10822873
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.4 = Counter32: 10461395
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.5 = Counter32: 121255964
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.6 = Counter32: 472674
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.7 = Counter32: 1152
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.8 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.9 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.10 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.11 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.12 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.13 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.14 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.15 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.16 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.17 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.18 = Counter32: 15366885
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.19 = Counter32: 13396828
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.20 = Counter32: 13388676
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.21 = Counter32: 15415497
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.22 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.23 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.24 = Counter32: 64
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.25 = Counter32: 17939782
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.26 = Counter32: 0
```

However, outputs of **ifInOctets** and **ifOutOctets** don't include **VLAN2(*.27)**.

Similar problem [ifInOctets but no ifOutOctets](https://lists.oetiker.ch/pipermail/mrtg/2010-July/036031.html) discussed, but ends up with response:

> However it doesn't bother our networks people since in==out and they
>   just look at the one that is available, so we've not bothered to talk
>   with Cisco about anything. ([Link](https://lists.oetiker.ch/pipermail/mrtg/2010-July/036034.html))

Anyone meet similar bugs and solved before?

Comment: From what I have been able to gather you want to get stats from a VLAN that your snmp client is not on? the only way I know how to do that is to have an interface on your monitoring system sat on that vlan, you may want to rephrase the question to make it more clear.

Comment: snmp server is configured on <cisco_switch_ip>, does a snmpwalk need a VLAN configuration? The weird part is: public IP address is configured on VLAN2 not VLAN1, suppose traffic should be captured on VLAN2, and both VLAN2/VLAN1 should be shown on IF-MIB. But now VLAN1 have traffic and VLAN2 even didn't shown on IF-MIB. Maybe the switch is too old...